# Having issue with Data Loader CLI

Tags: apex, data-loader, force-cli

I am having issue with Data Loader: 
Trying to use “update” providing Account Id to update custom field with fixed value. 
Map looks like this: 
ID=Id 
"Updated"=customObject__c Mapping for field customObject__c will be ignored since destination column is empty .

There were 1 successful updates and 0 errors. What could be the reason

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Are you expecting empty value for custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error. The upload should work fine. You are getting the warning because the mapping for customObject__c ( which would be an optional field) hasn't been provided.